# Connection Pooling in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, connection-pooling

I have to call a microservice(M1) from within another microservice(M2). And since there are going to be a lot of http requests to M1, I am using a connection pool and I am using the persistent gem, please check out the link https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/persistent_http/2.0.3. 
I have made the two methods in the class as self-send_get_message and self-send_post_message. 
So Whenever I have to make a request, I am calling the method directly by class reference. Is this the correct way of defining the pool and using the Get and Post methods.

```
class HttpClientPool
    @@persistent_http = PersistentHTTP.new(
                         name: 'MyHTTPClient',
                         logger: Rails.logger,
                         pool_size: 10,
                         warn_timeout: 0.25,
                         force_retry: true,
                         url: "http://m1.com/",
                         read_timeout: 2,
                         open_timeout: 1,
                         )
    @@x =  1

def self.send_get_message(path)
        puts "--path = #{path}"
        @@x= @@x+1
        puts "---var is #{@@x}"
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(path)
        @@persistent_http.request(request)
 end
 end
```

Now whenever I call HttpClientPool.send_get_message for sending a get request and print @@x the value should be incremented. When I am doing this on local machine - it seems to be fine. But when I deploy on a remote server, the value @@x comes out randomly mostly 2,3,4,5,6 and not seem to consistently increase.

Answer (score 0):

What type of server do you have?
On your local machine, ruby internal thread lock might make the variable increase consistently, but on a multi-threaded environments, it could be accessed and incremented in a "random" way.

By the way: x is a terrible name for a variable and, as regards to a basically persistent HTTP request architecture, wouldn't it be more suitable to use WebSockets or another type of connection architecutre?

Comment: I have deployed it on GCP in kubernetes cluster, with one replica and a load balancer as exposing service. So its a single pod, that's why I am confused about the random increment of value of x. P.S. yeah its a terrible name for a variable, just put it there for testing.

Comment: is there any gem for web-sockets in rails, any good one with proper documentation

Comment: Rails has "action cable" to work with websockets, both on the client and server side: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html

Comment: If your pod runs a threaded ruby environment, the random increment to x is completely expected. It doesn't mean that the requests are not being sent, just that they are not sent in any particular order because of the non-deterministic way in which the threads run. 
You can read about vanilla ruby's GIL (global interpreter lock) to understand why this might be happening on your cluster.